# cual seria la manera correcta de trabajar este cursor,

Tags: sql-server

Lo que deseo hacer es esto, 
hacer lectura de la tabla de la fecha menor a la mayor, haciendo la validación un `if` si el campo `[MovementType] = Debit`, de lo contrario se resta. ejemplo:
(orden de abajo para arriba)

```
[AccountMovementID][InmateID][MovementDate][MovementValue][MovementType][BalanceAfter]

101200  18576   2000-06-23 12:05:00.000    10.55    CREDIT  9.45
101199  18576   2000-06-16 14:01:00.000    20.00    DEBIT   20.00
101198  18576   1999-12-13 11:00:00.000    17.00    CREDIT  0.00
101197  18576   1999-12-02 03:15:00.000    17.00    DEBIT   17.00
```

-En el registro inferior tengo 17 de valor en el campo `[MovementValue]` y al ser debit me queda 17 en el `[BalanceAfter]`.
-En el registro superior al anterior tengo 17 de valor en el campo `[MovementValue]` y al ser Credit me queda  0 en el `[BalanceAfter]` ya que este debe ser restado del `[BalanceAfter]` de la primera lectura.

```
DECLARE @AccountMovementID int,
        @InmateID int,
        @MovementDate datetime,
        @MovementValue int,
        @MovementType nvarchar(20),
        @BalanceAfter int = 0

declare actualizar cursor  
    for select [AccountMovementID],
    [InmateID],
    [MovementDate],
    [MovementValue],
    [MovementType],
    [BalanceAfter]
    from [JMS_Account_Movement] where [InmateID] = 18576 order by [MovementDate] asc

OPEN actualizar
FETCH NEXT FROM actualizar INTO @AccountMovementID,
    @InmateID,
    @MovementDate,
    @MovementValue,
    @MovementType,
    @BalanceAfter

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
        if(@MovementType = 'DEBIT')
         begin 
            select @BalanceAfter = @BalanceAfter + @MovementValue
            --set @banderaCalorAnterior =@valorAnterior
         end
        else
          begin
            select @BalanceAfter = @BalanceAfter - @MovementValue
            --set @banderaCalorAnterior = @valorAnterior
          end

    update jms_account_movement set [BalanceAfter] = @BalanceAfter  where [AccountMovementID] = @AccountMovementID
    print    convert(varchar, @AccountMovementID) +'--'+ convert(varchar,@BalanceAfter)

         FETCH NEXT FROM actualizar INTO  @AccountMovementID,
                                            @InmateID,
                                            @MovementDate,
                                            @MovementValue,
                                            @MovementType,
                                            @BalanceAfter

END 

CLOSE actualizar
DEALLOCATE actualizar
```

Comment: qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: la version 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás usando SQL Server 2014, entonces lo mejor es que no uses un cursor, de hecho. Simplemente trata lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MovementType = 'DEBIT' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * MovementValue)
        OVER(PARTITION BY InmateID ORDER BY MovementDate) BalanceAfter
FROM dbo.JMS_Account_Movement
;
```

Comment: por favor, quizás me pueda usted explicar el código que me indico, me parece muy interesante, tengo muchas ganas de aprender recién termine mi carrera técnica.

Comment: Me encanta la solución de Lamak, de hecho he llegado un poco tarde a verlo pero en cuanto he visto cursores he pensado... ¿no se puede hacer directo? Pero Lamak ya había encontrado la respuesta correcta. @Franco, tendrás que mirar sobre SQL Server WINDOW FUNCTIONS. Encontrarás mucho escrito sobre el tema.E.g. [SELECT: cláusula OVER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Por cierto Franco... ya que Lamak ha resuelto tan brillantemente tu problema y encima te ha ayudado a eliminar los molestos y lentos cursores creo que lo mínimo que podías hacer es seleccionar su respuesta como correcta y votar su solución...

Comment: @FRANCOANELUBALDEARENAS En efecto, lo más fácil sería que revises el link que puso Angel. Pero básicamente es una suma acumulativa ordenada por fecha, y que empieza de cero al cambiar el valor de `InmateID`. (PD: @Angel, yo no puedo seleccionar la respuesta jeje)

Comment: @AngelM. si, marcaré las respuesta, de verdad les desagradecer bastante por su ayuda y paciencia.  les deseo un buen día... :)

Comment: Perdona Lamak... jajaja... me bailaron los nombres en mi primera versión del comentario pero... ya lo he arreglado !!!